# wxPython showing help upon mouse focus

Tags: python, wxpython

I wonder if there is any easy way to popup help (stickies style) upon focusing the mouse on a wx.Button for a second or two. 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`wx.ToolTip`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ToolTip.html). An example:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, title, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyFrame, self).__init__(None, title=title, *args, **kwargs)
    panel  = wx.Panel(self)
    button = wx.Button(panel, label="Button")
    tooltip = wx.ToolTip("Try to click this button")
    button.SetToolTip(tooltip)

class MyApp(wx.App):
  def OnInit(self):
    self.frame = MyFrame("Example")
    self.frame.Show()
    return True

MyApp(False).MainLoop()
```

[image: wx.ToolTip]

There are [some methods](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ToolTip.html#method-summary-methods-summary) you can use for controlling the tip.